# Connecting to database using Hibertane and JSP

Tags: hibernate, jsp

I have tried to connect to database using hibernate and JSP and below is my code.

I got [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6hbh.jpg)

I want to connect to hibernate using JSP only as anyways it would be converted to Servlet internally.

I am learning it on my own so kindly let me know if there is some silly mistake.

```
index.html

<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="action.jsp" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name = "name"> <br>
    Password <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


action.jsp

<%@page import="org.hibernate.Transaction"%>
<%@page import="p1.User"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%
       Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
//      out.println("Configuration object created");
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses = sf.openSession();
        Transaction t = ses.beginTransaction();

        String n = request.getParameter("name");
        String p = request.getParameter("password");

       // out.println("Welcome " + n);
        User u1 = new User(n, p);
        ses.save();
        t.commit();
        ses.close();
        out.println("Data inserted successfully");

     %>
</body>
</html>

hibernate.cfg.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate         Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-    configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property                                   name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/form?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">tiger</property>
    <mapping resource="p1/hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>


hibernate.hbm.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="p1.User" table="user">
        <property name="name" column="uname"></property>
        <property name="password" column="password"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the `hibernate.hbm.xml`

```
http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
```

This `DTD` can be used for the `hibernate.cfg.xml` only.
Refer this for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm

And, please, don't use DTD for the very old hibernate versions from `http://hibernate.sourceforge.net`.

And you don't save your `User`.

Comment: I have saved the session object now i.e.; ses.save() and I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: @krrish The problem is not with save, but with an invalid DTD. And `ses.save()` looks like bullshit. Do you think that `Session` is something like a telepath to know all about `User`?

Comment: I am learning hibernate for the first time and on my own hence there might be mistakes.
Kindly let me know if I need to change the DTD in mapping and cfg file or only one and to what it should be change.
Also advise how should I save data to database to database if ses.save is not a good idea.

Comment: @krrish Better to change DTD in both — `cfg` and `hbm`. You can find a valid DTD in the any Hibernate (3,4,5) tutorials. Use `ses.save(u1)` to save a user.

Comment: I tried some other DTD but they were of no use. Also the DTD used in the example were also used in other projects and it worked fine. I tried to create SessionFactory object as follows instead of creating it from configuration file but even it was of no use.

SessionFactory sf = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

Comment: @krrish `SAXParseException` means that XML can't be parsed.

Comment: If possible could anyone of you please try this example in your system to let me know where I am going wrong as I need a solution for above as I am doing my last year project in same.